# Clojure Regex: given a string, how can I return valid URLs in that string?

Tags: regex, clojure, jvm, clojurescript

I am trying to return valid URLs (as a substring) in a string in Clojurescript, what Regular Expression can I use?

```
(re-find #"regex for valid URL" "You can visit www.google.com")
=> "www.google.com"
(re-find #"regex for valid URL" "<b>www.google.com</b>")
=> "www.google.com"
(re-find #"regex for valid URL" "<b>www.google.com</b> and www.yahoo.com")
=> "www.google.com, www.yahoo.com"
```

Comment: How are you defining a valid URL? `example.com` is valid, as is `a.b.c.d.e.f.example.co.uk`. Will you support unicode characters in the domain name? Do you need support for URL-encoded strings, parameters, and subdomains?

Comment: This isn't a question about clojure, the jvm, or clojurescript. You're just asking for someone to write a regex for you; and they aren't even sure what flavor of regex to use because you've added multiple conflicting language tags.

Comment: @amalloy a regex is exactly what I'm asking for.

Comment: @OnlineCop Yeah I wasn't being too clear, and I didn't think about that before hand. I guess I was only thinking of example.com, www.example.com but nothing advanced like encoded strings. a.b.c.d.e.f.example.co.uk seems fine too. I was using this `#"^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|org|me|io|net|co|edu|uk|ca|de|jp|fr|au|us|ru|ch|it|nl|se|no|es)$"`

Comment: Well, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/161738/625403 - if what you want is a regex that matches any URL that's legal according to the IETF spec, you are kinda in for something that a bit longer than your attempt.

Comment: goog.string.linkify.findFirstUrl: https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/32365aba43acb36c5d693256ef5d4dbe3bddddfe/closure/goog/string/linkify_test.js#L334-L357

Given that you want multiple ones you may have to call the function in a loop and substring until nothing is found anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how carefully you want your script to validate the URL, the regex you provided, as long as you get rid of the '^' and '$' anchors, works fairly well ([as seen here](https://regex101.com/r/vF6zJ0/1)).

Note that I added some whitespace in the regex just for readability.

There are several issues that I see from that regex (as you can probably see on that page). It matches in places where it shouldn't (such as repeated `..` characters), and sites with `.co.uk` are matching the `.co` portion along with the domain name and `.uk` separately. That, by itself, can be fairly easy to fix just simply adding those edge cases directly into the second group (the one with `(com|org|...)`).

The reason you'll need to remove the '^' and '$' anchors is that the pattern will only match if the URL is the only thing on the line: `^` has to match at the beginning of the line, and `$` can only match at the end. Having `<b>www.google.com</b>` means that the `<b>` will make the `^` anchor fail to match the URL since it's not starting at the beginning of the line.

The other suggestions, such as @amalloy's link, gives a much more comprehensive solution and will match everything correctly, but it is very complex.

So knowing exactly what you want to match, and what you're willing to ignore/trade/give up, will help craft something that works for you.